# IO::Pty perl module cpan solaris installation

Tags: perl, perl-module, cpan

OS is SunOS 5.10 Generic_150400-01 sun4v sparc sun4v.  Tried to install IO::Pty perl module via cpan. Got an error related to compiler  Tried to Set the PATH env variable to /opt/solarisstudio12.3/bin  and modified cpan myconfig.pm to have 'make_arg' => q[CC=/opt/solarisstudio12.3/bin/cc] .  But still getting the same error.

```
cpan> install IO::Pty
CPAN: Storable loaded ok
Going to read /home/D99134/cpan/Metadata
  Database was generated on Sat, 09 Nov 2013 06:53:04 GMT
Running install for module IO::Pty
Running make for T/TO/TODDR/IO-Tty-1.10.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::MD5 loaded ok
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok
Checksum for /home/D99134/cpan/sources/authors/id/T/TO/TODDR/IO-Tty-1.10.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /home/D99134/cpan/build for sizes
x IO-Tty-1.10, 0 bytes, 0 tape blocks
x IO-Tty-1.10/ChangeLog, 8192 bytes, 16 tape blocks
x IO-Tty-1.10/MANIFEST, 151 bytes, 1 tape blocks
x IO-Tty-1.10/META.yml, 612 bytes, 2 tape blocks
x IO-Tty-1.10/Makefile.PL, 13360 bytes, 27 tape blocks
x IO-Tty-1.10/Pty.pm, 8709 bytes, 18 tape blocks
x IO-Tty-1.10/README, 1686 bytes, 4 tape blocks
x IO-Tty-1.10/Tty.pm, 7526 bytes, 15 tape blocks
x IO-Tty-1.10/Tty.xs, 22244 bytes, 44 tape blocks
x IO-Tty-1.10/t, 0 bytes, 0 tape blocks
x IO-Tty-1.10/t/test.t, 7306 bytes, 15 tape blocks
x IO-Tty-1.10/try, 2880 bytes, 6 tape blocks
Removing previously used /home/D99134/cpan/build/IO-Tty-1.10

  CPAN.pm: Going to build T/TO/TODDR/IO-Tty-1.10.tar.gz

Now let's see what we can find out about your system
(logfiles of failing tests are available in the conf/ dir)...

ERROR: cannot run the configured compiler '/opt/SUNWspro/bin/cc'
(see conf/compilerok.log). Suggestions:
1) The complier '/opt/SUNWspro/bin/cc' is not in your PATH. Add it
   to the PATH and try again. OR
2) The compiler isn't installed on your system. Install it. OR
3) You only have a different compiler installed (e.g. 'gcc').
   Either fix the compiler config in the perl Config.pm
   or install a perl that was built with the right compiler
   (you could build perl yourself with the available compiler).

Note: this is a system-administration issue, please ask your local
admin for help. Thank you.

make: Fatal error: No arguments to build
  /usr/ccs/bin/make CC=/opt/solarisstudio12.3/bin/cc -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow the third suggestion (fixing perl's `Config.pm`). This is dangerous, but there's a CPAN module which allows you to do `Config.pm` changes on the fly: [ExtUtils::FakeConfig](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3A%3AFakeConfig). Just follow the instructions in the documentation.

Here's another article about editing `Config.pm` on perlmonks: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=570684